# yet another simple Laplace transform

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, laplace-transform

what is $ℒ(t^2e^{3t})$

I have got this far so far:

$=\int_{0}^\infty (t^2e^{t(3-s)})$

Integration by parts using:

$u = t^2$ and $du = 2t$

$v = \frac{e^{t(3-2)}}{3-s}$ and $dv = e^{t(3-s)}$

Which I think yields: $0 - \int_{0}^\infty \frac{2t}{3-s} e^{t(3-2)}$

and now i'm stuck. if someone could do a step by step instructions, that would be so helpful!

Comment: Your integral should include an $e^{-st}$

Comment: oops it was, I meant to put an s instead of a 2 in the second equation - corrected now

Comment: You're integrating with respect to $t$ correct? Then can't you simply factor out constants, repeat integration by parts and then split this?

Comment: What's the asterisk?

Comment: got rid of the asterisk not sure what that was doing there, @mathtastic i believe that was what i did in answer to Varun's answer? i didnt factor out the constants at the start tho, what would it look like if they were taken out before integration?

Comment: If you already know $L(t^2)$, then you can use $L(f(t)e^{at})=F(s-a)$ where $L(f(t))=F(s)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider 
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\mathcal{L}\{e^{3t}\},
$$
Can you easily determine the Laplace transform of of $e^{3t}$? If so, what is the second derivative in $s$?

---

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{3t}e^{-st}dt &= \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}e^{3t}e^{-st}dt\\
&= \int_0^{\infty}t^2e^{3t}e^{-st}dt\\
&= \mathcal{L}\{t^2e^{3t}\}
\end{align}

Comment: $\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{t(3-s)}$ ? 

which would be: $\frac{e^{t(3-s)}}{3-s}$ which would just be infinity when subbing in the limits?

feel like im going wrong somewhere?

Comment: $$\mathcal{L}\{e^{3t}\} = \frac{e^{-(s-3)t}}{s-3}\biggr|_0^{\infty}$$ The limit at inifity goes to zero and when t = 0, we get 1.

Comment: oh of course, sorry! e to the limit of -infinity is 0, ok i get that? so what was your point about the second derivative?

Comment: no i'm not sure i understand? is there no integration involved?

Comment: @JabbaWook see edit for clarification. Do you see why we can solve $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\mathcal{L}\{e^{3t}\}$ instead of $\mathcal{L}\{t^2e^{3t}\}$?

Comment: ohh so is the second derivative of s, $t^2$?! 

so the trick at the start would have been to recognise that $t^2$ was the second derivative of s and sub out?

Comment: @JabbaWook yes, you can use the trick generally when you have $t^n\cos(t)$, $t^n\sin(t)$, and $t^ne^t$. This allows you take a Laplace transform of something easier and then differentiate the solution.

Comment: thank you so much! thats a really helpful tip I cant believe I never came across in my lectures!

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the Laplace Transform of:

$$t^2e^{3t}$$

Your integral should be:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} t^2e^{3t}e^{-st}dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^2e^{t(3-s)}dt$$

Using integration by parts, with $u = t^2$ and $dv = e^{t(3-s)}$

We then get:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} t^2e^{t(3-s)}dt = \frac{t^2e^{t(3-s)}}{3-s} - \int \frac{e^{t(3-s)}2t}{3-s}dt$$

You would then perform integration by parts again, this time with: $u = 2x$ and $dv = \frac{e^{t(3-s)}}{3-s}$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I got as far as completing the first integration by parts and agree with your answer, but it didnt feel right having another integral to do so i went looking for help. but if im on the right track then i'll carry on and let you know my answer to the second IBP in just a second

Comment: so doing it this way do you get the second integration by parts as: $\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{2e^{t(3-s)}}{{(3-s)}^2}$?